# Is linux kernel timer running as a separate thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, timer, kernel

What happens when a new timer is registered and its function run   will it create a new thread of execution for each new timer we create?

To me it should create a new thread because when we create 2 timers they should be running independently from each other, right?

In my code I use 2 timers created from a single common thread and I am curious to find out if they behave like separate threads.

Thanks,
Przemek

Comment: And what do you except each thread to do? poll the timer in a loop?

Comment: Hello, mayby I wasn't precise in my post: I start a timer and its function runs in a loop every 5 msec which is what I want. What I wanted to know is: if I start multiple timers like that will each of the functions (timers) be running in its own thread? So, does a timer's function run in a separate thread to the thread timer was created in?

Comment: Those timer threads, what do you expect them to do? Poll a hardware timer in a loop?

Comment: Timer function will just be calling a notification function to another layer of driver in a loop. The notification is to the ALSA driver layer that we have audio for it ready to capture. Very simple. But since there can be simultaneous audio captures, there will be multiple timers running and it's important that they are independent from each other and independent from the thread which created them. It looks to me like kernel timers run in their own threads but I could not find confirmation online...